# How to assign the exact number of tasks assigned to each user

Tags: python

My task is to a read file named tasks.txt(where there are the tasks assign to each user and then I have compared with the username_storage list, if their names are in the tasks.txt files it should increase by one and then move to the other user, until the list is completed .

My task is to output the number of tasks assigned to each user.

I have tried to do that but it doesn't show me the exact number of tasks for each user, below you can see my code.

**THIS IS THE TEXT FILE**

```
admin, Register Users with taskManager.py, Use taskManager.py to add the usernames and passwords for all team members that will be using this program., 10 Oct 2019, 20 Oct 2019, No

admin, Assign initial tasks, Use taskManager.py to assign each team member with appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Oct 2019, No

banta, FCB, This task is to find new young talents for futbol club barcelona, 20 Jan 2023, 2023-01-07, Yes

banta, Programming, Why do you love to program, 31 Jan 2023, 2023-01-08, No
```

I have included that answer in the previous question`

**MY FIRST TRY:**

```
tasks_for_user = 0
username_storage = ['admin', 'banta', 'david,', 'hyperionDev', 'rebeca']
tasks = open("tasks.txt", "r")
i = 0
for task in tasks:
    split = task.strip().split(", ")
    while i < len(username_storage):
        if username_storage[i] == split[0]:
            tasks_for_user += 1
            print(f"There are {tasks_for_user} tasks assigned to {username_storage[i]}")
            i += 1
        else:
            tasks_for_user = 0
            print(f"There are {tasks_for_user} tasks assigned to {username_storage[i]}")
            i += 1
```

**THIS IS THE OUTPUT**

```
There are 1 tasks assigned to admin
There are 0 tasks assigned to banta
There are 0 tasks assigned to david,
There are 0 tasks assigned to hyperionDev
There are 0 tasks assigned to rebeca
```

**MY SECOND TRY**

```
for users_ in username_storage:
    for task in tasks:
        split = task.strip().split(", ")
        if users_ == split[0]:
            tasks_for_user += 1
        else:
            tasks_for_user += 0
    print(f"There are {tasks_for_user} tasks assigned to {users_}")
```

**THIS IS THE OUTPUT**

```
There are 2 tasks assigned to admin
There are 2 tasks assigned to banta
There are 2 tasks assigned to david,
There are 2 tasks assigned to hyperionDev
There are 2 tasks assigned to rebeca
```

Comment: Try creating a dictionary of users instead of a list of users. They key would be  the usernames, and the values would be the number of tasks for that username. When you encounter a username in the txt file, increment that username's value by one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the task_for_user is being applied to all of the different users. So it will keep being incremented not depending on who it is being incremented for. You could instead use a dictionary to map the tasks assigned to the user, this keeps the number of tasks localised to just that user.

Comment: I lovebuzz thanks for the suggestion. Is just that I'm a little bit confused with it. 
Could you provide me with an example or elaborate it a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty dictionary called `task_count` which will be used to store the number of tasks for each user.

```
tasks = open("tasks.txt", "r")
task_count = {}
for line in tasks:
    task_info = line.strip().split(",")
    username = task_info[0]
    if username in task_count:
        task_count[username] += 1
    else:
        task_count[username] = 1

for user in task_count:
    print(f"There are {task_count[user]} tasks assigned to {user}")
```